# jquery table offsetWidth question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been looking into this for some hours now and can't figure it out. 
I am trying to write some code to align table headers and table columns,
I am trying to figure out the overall width of the header cell and the width of a column. 
but for some strange reason `tdOffset` gets a value and `thOffset` is `NaN`.

```
$("#tblTasks tbody tr:eq(0) td").each(function(index)
{
    tdOffset = parseInt(this.offsetWidth);

    thEl = $('#tblTasks thead tr:eq(0) th:eq(' + index.toString() + ')').first();
    thOffset = parseInt(thEl.offsetWidth);

    alert('tdOffSet' + tdOffset + ' thOffset:' + thOffset);
}
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks and be happy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that `this.offsetWidth` works and `thEl.offsetWidth` does not is that `this` refers to a DOM element and `thEl` refers to a jQuery object.

You can get access to the DOM element "behind" thOffset by doing the following

```
thEl[0].offsetWidth
```

Comment: Thanks so much I have spent so much time on this.

Comment: A best practice is to put $ on variables that are jQuery objects.  It helps you keep track.  $thEl